# Cmd. exe error occurred when compiling C file with VSCode + Clang in win environment

Tags: c, gdi, vscode-tasks

I write a new .c file named `helloengine_win.c` and use shortcuts `shift + ctrl + b` to complier it.
The `tasks.json` is :

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang.exe",
        "command": "D:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-L",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.19041.0\\um\\x64\\User32.Lib",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.19041.0\\um\\x64\\Gdi32.Lib"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "D:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\**"
            
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "\"D:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang.exe\""
    }
]
```

}

The file uses `GetStockObject()` so I need the lib `User32.Lib` and `Gdi32.lib`

But when I complier the file I get :
`spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT generation is complete, but an error occurred`

I have confirmed that all library files exist and no errors are reported in the documentation.I don't konw what's wrong.